# GDAL GCP Transform - No GeoTransform() on GCP projected image?

Tags: python, gdal, ground-control

I have a block of code that applies GCPs I have calculated to spatially project an image. Essentially, I am projecting the image by defining the corners as points 1,2,3,4.

```py
# Set ground control points
gcp_list = [] 
gcp_list.append(gdal.GCP(X3, Y3 ,0,0,imh))   #sorted x , y , z , col , row
gcp_list.append(gdal.GCP(X4,Y4, 0,imw,imh))
gcp_list.append(gdal.GCP(X1,Y1, 0,imw,0 ))
gcp_list.append(gdal.GCP(X2,Y2 ,0,0,0))

# Export dataset
outdataset.SetProjection('PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-117],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32611"]]')
wkt = outdataset.GetProjection() 
outdataset.SetGCPs(gcp_list,wkt)
outdataset = None
```

However, I am trying to figure out how to 'track' different pixels throughout the transform. That is, how do I figure out where pixel (1000,2000) (in the original image) ends up spatially?
Next, I figured I could read that image back in, get its GeoTransform(), and apply that to the box I have

```py
# Project the box
ortho = gdal.Open(im_file.replace('.JPG','.tif'))
x0, px_w, py_w, y0, px_h, py_h = ortho.GetGeoTransform()
# Example box
box = [2640,1886,2640+216,1886+212]
xmin_geo = box[0] * px_w + x0
ymin_geo = box[1] * px_w + y0
xmax_geo = box[2] * px_w + x0
ymax_geo = box[3] * px_w + y0
```

However, in the above code, x0 = 0, px_w = 1, etc. Its like the tif file does not have a geotransform, even though when I load it into QGIS it spatially projects perfectly

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geotransform and ground control points are two different ways for defining the correlation between pixel coordinates and geographic coordinates. See https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html

> GDAL datasets have two ways of describing the relationship between
> raster positions (in pixel/line coordinates) and georeferenced
> coordinates. The first, and most commonly used is the affine transform
> (the other is GCPs).
>
> A dataset can have a set of control points relating one or more
> positions on the raster to georeferenced coordinates. All GCPs share a
> georeferencing coordinate system (returned by
> GDALDataset::GetGCPProjection()).

It is possible to convert the GCP georeferenced image into GeoTransform image for example with gdalwarp.

```
gdalwarp gcp_image_if.tif geotransform_image_out.tif
```